# How submit button works without `type="submit"`

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm checking this example in react-hook-form doc: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-v6-controller-qsd8r?file=/src/index.js

Weird thing is that the button doesn't have `type="submit"`. But it still triggers submit event after clicking. (Screenshot attached below.)
[image]

How does it know which button is the submit button?

Comment: As a side node: if multiple `<button>` elements are left without either `type="submit"` or `"type="button"`, the latter will always be placed by default no-matter-what, so you'll have multiple buttons being able to submit the form. `type="button"` strips the submit ability.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If a `button` is inside a `form`, then by default it is given the `submit` type, unless you give it another type.

So the Reset button in that codesandbox has `type="button"` to prevent it triggering the event, but the Submit button leaves it blank, so it submits by default.

Reference: [Moz Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type)